# Install Sqitch Perl CPAN module on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, cpan, sqitch

I'm trying to install sqitch on Windows 10 after installing it with CPAN using latest Strawberry Perl.

```
cat NEWS >ReleaseNotes
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'ReleaseNotes'
GUIDO/libintl-perl-1.26.tar.gz
C:\Projects\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Locale::Messages'.
```

Unfortunately dependency Locale::Messages fails to install. Is it trying to invoke linux "cat" command on Windows? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You should have the `bin` directory from your Strawberry installtion in your `PATH`. All the scripts that come with Perl modules (just like `perl` itself, or `prove`), go there.

Comment: @simbabque Yes, I actually have 3 bins from Strawberry in path. That does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just installed `App::Sqitch` on my copy of Strawberry Perl

It has created this file

```
C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin\sqitch.bat
```

If you don't have that file then it sounds like your installation didn't work properly

If you do have that file, but you cannot run it without providing the full path, then `C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin` isn't in your PATH

Comment: Please take a look, I've did a reinstall and run Perl Commandline with administrator. It seems one of the dependencies fails to intstall.

Comment: @Cortlendt: Yes. I had problems with `Locale::Messages` and `Locale::TextDomain`. `Type::Tiny::XS` is also "recommended". I fixed it by using `cpan` to get the `cpan> ` prompt and then using `install Locale::Messages` etc. to install them individually. It all seemed okay like that. Don't forget to `install App::Sqitch` as well when you're done.

Comment: It works if you run CPAN> from bash console.It has "cat"  command.

Answer (score -1):

The [module](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Sqitch) provides the `sqitch` command, which is [documented here](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-Sqitch/lib/sqitch.pod), call it from the command line like so:

```
sqitch [<options>] <command> [<command-options>] [<args>]
```

Note that the documentation has links to associated tutorials and other references to learn how to use it.

sqitch installed here by default:

```
root@test:~# which sqitch
/usr/local/bin/sqitch
```

Try searching for the file from the command line of Windows.
Just grab it from here and place it in your path:

https://github.com/theory/sqitch/blob/master/bin/sqitch

Comment: The problem is Cortlendt doesn't know where to find the command.

Comment: Exactly >sqitch
'sqitch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche the update is a bit cryptic, I don't understand. There is no *sqitch*.* on my disk.

Comment: @Cortlendt I posted a link to download the file you don't have, it's just a perl script as you can see.

Comment: Trying to run said file as a Perl Script: >perl sqitch
Too late for "-CAS" option at sqitch line 1.

Comment: read the docs: "Note: Since perl 5.10.1, if the -C option is used on the "#!" line, it must be specified on the command line as well, since the standard streams are already set up at this point in the execution of the perl interpreter." http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-C-%5B_number/list_%5D%2a a google search would have found this for you

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche: It's generally not very helpful to offer people bits and pieces of your own installation. For one thing it may be specific to your own build, and for another, Windows installations create a .bat file and running the Perl code directly is incorrect.